# Error SearchView in Action Bar

Tags: android, search

I would like to create a SearchView in my application, but I have a strange error. I dont know why, but I can search only the first element of my list. I cant  search other elements.  I must add, that i am an amateur in Android so forgive me this probably stupid question.

Below is my Main Activity class and Data Adapter

Thanks in advance

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DataAdapter dataAdapter;
private List<ModelJsona> dataArrayList;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initViews();





}

private void initViews(){
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    loadJSON();
}

private void loadJSON(){
    dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://restcountries.eu/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    RequestInterface requestInterface=retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    Call<List<ModelJsona>> call= requestInterface.getJSON();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ModelJsona>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ModelJsona>> call, Response<List<ModelJsona>> response) {
            dataArrayList = response.body();
            dataAdapter=new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),dataArrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }



        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ModelJsona>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error",t.getMessage());
        }






    });
}


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);
    search(searchView);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void search(SearchView searchView) {

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

}

**Data Adapter:**

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<ModelJsona> dataList;
private List<ModelJsona> FdataList;


public DataAdapter(Context context, List<ModelJsona> dataList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.FdataList=dataList;

}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.country_name.setText(dataList.get(position).getName());
    holder.country_region.setText(dataList.get(position).getRegion());
    holder.country_topleveldomain.setText(dataList.get(position).getTopLevelDomain().toString());
    holder.country_nativename.setText(dataList.get(position).getNativeName());




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return FdataList.size();
}



public Filter getFilter() {

    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

            String charString = charSequence.toString();

            if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                FdataList    = dataList;
            } else {

                ArrayList<ModelJsona> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (ModelJsona androidVersion : dataList) {

                    if (    androidVersion.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString) ||
                            androidVersion.getRegion().toLowerCase().contains(charString) ||
                            androidVersion.getTopLevelDomain().contains(charString) ||
                            androidVersion.getNativeName().contains(charString))


                    {

                        filteredList.add(androidVersion);
                    }
                }

                FdataList = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = FdataList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            FdataList = (ArrayList<ModelJsona>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put SearchView in onCreate not in onCreateOptionsMenu .

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


           searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchBar);



            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                    //put your filter here
                    //contentAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: It doesnt work , because my searchView is connected with MenuItem